# odd, rare but problematic behavior accessing a jquery UI input autocomplete's value on click of a button

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, onchange

Basically, im having a hard time getting the correct value from a jquery UI input with a autocomplete at times. Iv created a jsfiddle to demonstrate the behavior. Hard to explain the exact issue, but here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/B4mXH/14/

To reproduce, follow these steps exactly, while having the browser dev tools js console open:

1. focus on the text input
2. move the mouse away from the input
3. type c
4. press arrow down on the keyboard to select "abc"
5. hover over the option "cde"
6. click the button.

error: I wont get any value. undefined is logged to the console.
expected: whatever value is inside the input box. please =)

If it matters, im using chrome.

Comment: What jQuery and jQuery UI versions are you using? The ones in fiddle don't really match, try this fiddle with jQuery 1.8.1 and UI 1.8.23 http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/jyCgr/4/

Comment: Also, I tried multiple times and didn't manage to reproduce the issue on either fiddle with Chrome 21 stable nor 23 Canary.

Comment: I tried your fiddle and im having the same problem. My chrome is up to date. Care to review the steps, and try again? Maybe I need to record a video ;)

Comment: Focus, move mouse away, c, down, hover over `cde`, click. Done a couple times already. Yeah, maybe a video can help. `:P`

Comment: Here's the video! https://vimeo.com/49861808  =)

Comment: Oh the test button, now I see.

Comment: Change the `change` in `$('#autocomplete').change` to `blur`, seems to work for me http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/jyCgr/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you swap the `change` handler by a `blur` one it will work as intended:

```
$('#autocomplete').blur(function(event, ui) {
    value = $(this).val();
});
```

I'm not sure why, but I assume the UI programmatically fires `change` events which affect the outcome of your stored `value` variable.

Also, if you want to always get the current value of text input, you can query it when using it instead of storing it in a variable:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    console.log("clicked with : " + $('#autocomplete').val());
});
```

There may be some restriction on your project for you to not be using that yet, but it's the most bulletproof method if you can use it.

Comment: thanks for the blur solution. Our problem is a bit larger than the alternative solution though. We'r actually using a custom jquery widget, that fires a change event to update a knockout.js binding. its the actual knockout.js viewmodel we'r actually using in the click event...

Comment: I thought so. No problem. `=]`